# Communicating between modules using HTTP in Nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, nestjs

I have 2 modules in Nest.js let's call them Module1 and Module2. Module1 has an endpoint of /api/module1 and Module2 has /api/module2. I am trying to call Module2 from Module1 as below

```
return await this.httpService
    .post(url, data1, {
        headers: header
    })
    .pipe(
        map(res => {
        return res.data;
        }),
    );
```

Here the url is /api/module2 and data1 is the parameter i'm passing. When I make the call, this is what I see

```
{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false},"operator":{}}
```

I usually see this error when a promise is returned before it's fully done. Not sure what to do differently here. The method which is holding this httpService called is enclosed inside an async and the calling method has an await as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing there is a raw observable that hasn't been subscribed to, probably due to returning a promise instead of returning the observable. Nest's HttpService uses RxJS instead of async/await by default, but to fix this you can easily add a `.toPromise()` after the RxJS object and not worry about the subscription yourself.

As a side note: any reason to call the API via the HTTP module and not just call the service with the proper values directly? Seems like a lot of overhead for a REST call.

Comment: Thank you! I think adding the .toPromise() worked. So the reason i'm using the HTTP module is because I eventually want to go down the microservices approach and most likely will not be able to inject the service from Module2 into Module1. If I don't go down that path, is that what you suggest I do? Inject service from Module2 into Module1?

Comment: **When** your switch over to microservices, then that's something you should worry about, other, you're adding a lot of overhead for a simple call

Comment: Makes sense. Well if this is an enterprise application and the direction is to go microservices in the long run, wouldn't it make sense to just start off this way then? If not HTTP what would you recommend? Importing Module2 service inside Module1?

Comment: I guess my question is, how is this scenario best achieved with and without microservices in mind?